# Down facing triangle... but wait... what is this... with borders?

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I'm using the cool CSS here:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

I'm creating a simple triangle for something I'll be perfecting with some jQuery.  Problem is,  I need the triangle to have borders for two of its sides.  Seeing as the triangle is made out of borders, this is giving me a headache.

Take a look at this picture here:

[image]

I need sides A and B to have a border so they don't mix with the other orange.

Here is a peak at the css for the triangle itself:

```
.arrow-down {
        position:relative;
        top:30px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        padding-top:30px;
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-left:20px solid transparent;
        border-right:20px solid transparent;
        border-top:20px solid #FF6A00;
}
```

So, I'm open to alternate solutions (uncommon right?).  I would prefer a solution with my current setup just because I've already put a lot of work into it.  Either way though, I need this to have a border (I guess you could call me 'desperate').

Cheers and thanks a plenty for any help!

Comment: Are you willing to forsake IE? Or do you need to support a particular version (and above)?

Comment: @DavidThomas I really need support for IE7 and up sadly.  I'm publishing this for a virtual company and most of the clients have access to IE7.

Comment: Can you put a border on the word "CHECK" instead?

Comment: @JamesKhoury No, only because the arrow will be above the word.  Good idea though +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of conceptual idea, than a hard answer (I'm really not as good as you with CSS). But I've seen people do drop shadows by just placing an identical item in the same position as the top item, but offset by one or more pixels, and with a smaller z-index.

Perhaps you could do something like that in this case: make a second triangle, color it black, and position it one pixel lower (top:31px) than your main, red triangle. I think since it would be underneath the red triangle, it would also hide the top border, which is part of your requirements.

Comment: This is genius (I think).  I was already trying to think about something like this.  The problem with my thinking was that I was going the other way.  How was I going to make an inverted triangle.  Silly me.  Thanks, I'll test it out in a minute!

Answer (score 5):

with 'little' change you can achieve this, i'm not sure it is the best way but it sure works.

the idea is to have a second 'slightly larger' triangle positioned behind the orange one.

try a working example @ jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/e4ahw/

after putting the two triangles on top of each other, i move them up 2 pixels `top: -2px` so they lay on top of the orange box, and thus conceil the black border that runs around the div you want to have an arrow on :)

Comment: Sorry, user470714 answered first the same thing basically.  Your jsfiddle was nice but I kind of already figure how to do it.  +1 for the hard work though!

Comment: This helped me. For anyone who wants the arrow to be pointing to the left (and have a border), you can use my adjusted version: http://jsfiddle.net/e4ahw/4/

Answer (score 4):

I actually don't know if this will work on IE7...

```
.arrow-down {
        position:relative;
        top:30px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        padding-top:30px;
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-left:22px solid transparent;
        border-right:22px solid transparent;
        border-top:22px solid #000;
}
.arrow-down:before {
        content: '';
        position:absolute;
        top: -22px;
        left: -20px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        padding-top:30px;
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-left:20px solid transparent;
        border-right:20px solid transparent;
        border-top:20px solid #FF6A00;
}
```

my *hacky solution*
[See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ChuLh/1/)

Comment: Oooh I like, smart method.  I've already got it working sadly.  +1 for a great answer though!

Comment: you may need a `z-index` call on the overlay... maybe not.

Comment: I'm not having any issues with layering thus far.  Thanks for the suggestion though!  +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rSzds/1/

**CSS:**

```
.arrow-down-border {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        position:relative;
        border-left:22px solid transparent;
        border-right:22px solid transparent;
        border-top:22px solid black;

}
.arrow-down {
        padding:0px;
        position:absolute;
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-left:20px solid transparent;
        border-right:20px solid transparent;
        border-top:20px solid #FF6A00;
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-top: -21px;
        float: left;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="arrow-down-border">
    <div class="arrow-down">
    </div>
</div>
```

I haven't tested it in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a .arrow-down-border class, with black color, and a second triangular div.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h74M2/)

Answer (score -2):

&#9660 ▼

&#9661 ▽

&#9662 ▾

&#9663 ▿

&#9947 ⛛

&#9207 ⏷